# How to limit year in ajax calendar extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a Calendar Extender.

I want to show only current year in calendar.

User can not select 2010 as current year is 2011.

So how to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `StartDate` and `EndDate` properties to set a range of acceptable dates that you want to allow the user to select - you can set this in the markup as per [krolik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8589745/1738), or in the code-behind so you can set it to the current year e.g.

```
CalendarExtender.StartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year,1,1);
CalendarExtender.EndDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year,12,31);
```

Comment: startdate property is not there

Comment: @Vivek Make sure you've got the release from September 2011 (or later) the Start and EndDate properties were introduced in that release. The easiest way to do this is to install the AjaxControlToolkit from Nuget.

Answer (score 1):

Use **StartDate** property of your extender. For example:

```
<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="Calendar" StartDate="1/1/2011" runat="server" ... />
```

> **StartDate** - Indicates start date for range that available for selection.

Comment: Are you using CalendarExtender from [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)?