# Ajax tool kit Calendar Extender Limit Year selection

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Ajax tool kit calendar extender control, I want to limit the year selection from 1900 to current year only. I have seen here [Year Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589609/how-to-limit-year-in-ajax-calendar-extender) to use StartDate and EndDate
But when in code behind I am writing

```
calendarext.StartDate
```

its giving error

```
'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender' does not contain a definition for 'StartDate' and no extension method 'StartDate' accepting a first argument of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Even in designer I checked in properties window,there is no such property exists for this control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting a **new version** of Ajax control toolkit..The **Start** and **EndDate** properties were introduced in the releases after **September 2011**..I have getting both Start Date and  End Date properties on calendar extender..